# If-else condition using SQL query not executing?

Tags: sql

I want to use an `if`-`else` condition in an SQL query. Below I have listed my query. I am getting an error like:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub query is not introduced with EXISTS.

How can I execute this query?

```
if (select * from tblOfferDownloads where OfferId ='162')>0
Begin
select * from tblOfferDownloads
End
else
Begin
Select * from tbloffer
End
```

Comment: which db are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use EXISTS or COUNT. You get error because this SQL SELECT returns more than one row and you try to compare the rowset with 0.

```
if EXISTS(select COUNT(*) from tblOfferDownloads where OfferId ='162')
```

or

```
if (select COUNT(*) from tblOfferDownloads where OfferId ='162')>0
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement should be like this:

```
if EXISTS(select NULL from tblOfferDownloads where OfferId ='162')
BEGIN
....
```

Or with a count:

```
if (select COUNT(*) from tblOfferDownloads where OfferId ='162')>0
BEGIN
....
```